# Ionic md-tabs squeezing tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, ionic-v1

I have created this app with ionic and angular material design. My issue is when I use md-tabs with more than 4 tabs. It's squeezing when I switch between views and back to md-tabs... it's common on android, ios it's just usually.

```
<md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="auto" md-align-tabs="top" md-center-tabs="yes"
         md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom=""
         md-selected="data.selectedIndex">
```

Normal

[image]

With squeeze

[image]

> Solution

```
md-tab-item.md-tab.md-ink-ripple {
    min-width: 111px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please inspect the view in the browser and post a screenshot of the DOM hierarchy (classes and all) for the `<md-tabs>` element and its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `min-width` css property for the generated tab elements?